How could a lone island on an ocean planet have a temperate climate?
Grenaplaza is an Earth-like planet populated by a race of half human half pig people called the Gammonfolk. Grenaplaza is unique in that it is an ocean world with one lonely island on its surface, where the Gammonfolk live. This island has a mild, temperate climate, similar to the United Kingdom, perfect for its population of sycophantic, xenophobic pig people (picture the Shire if the Shire had a brexit vote)
My question is, how could you justify this island having a temperate climate when it's on its own?
The climate of western Europe is obviously dictated by numerous factors like surrounding landmasses and latitude that are absent here, so how would you find that on a solitary island on an ocean world? Or, better yet, how would you go about recreating this climate, given you had the means?
Assume the island is roughly the same size/area as the real UK, give or take 10%, and the planet is of a similar diameter to the real Earth.


why do you think the island being alone would matter? climate is mostly controlled by planetary convection cells.

@John My main worry was that an island exposed to such a nonstop continuous expanse of ocean would be completely vulnerable to weather events like hurricanes that could form and hit completely unobstructed

preventing hurricanes is a very diffrent question than climate, you may want to edit your question, there is a way to solve that but it means putting it on the equator. teperate climate and no hurricanes are mutually exclusive.

Anywhere other than the tropics, near the poles or horse latitudes
Assuming the temperature, day length, axial tilt and eccentricity of Grenaplaza are like Earth, anywhere outside of the tropics, tundra and desert belts should have a temperate oceanic influence.
Your oceans cover most of the planet and so your island will have plenty of moderating influence which will prevent continental climates from forming. The southern hemisphere of Earth already has this because South America and Africa (in the south) taper too much, while Australia is too small.
To get your island to be oceanic, simply make sure its latitude is within an isotherm that is >10°C and <18°C (in its coldest month). This is so the climate will not be tundra/icecap or tropical.
Then, make sure your island is not within 15-30° north or south as these are the horse latitudes and will likely lead to more arid conditions, especially with areas facing cold currents.
Lastly, ensure your island doesn’t have any extremely high mountains that could block moisture and lead to lower alpine temperatures at their peaks.
If I had to give an approximate as to where to put your island, I would say 40° latitude north or south. This is roughly the latitude of New Zealand on Earth.
